# Generate an XML file from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, xml

Each customer has a unique ID and multiple bills. Now I want to generate an xml file from mysql database using PHP. I have given below the sample data and XML format required.

Database Table Structure :

```
ID  CUSTOMERNAME    BILLNO  BILLAMOUNT
1   RAM             1000    3000
2   RAJ             1001    3500
2   RAJ             1002    5000
3   RAVI            1003    3250
```

No primary key or autoincrement is used for the ID.

MySQL query to create above table:

```
CREATE TABLE `xml`.`customer` (`ID` INT NULL , `CUSTOMERNAME` VARCHAR(250) NULL , `BILLNO` INT NOT NULL , `BILLAMOUNT` DOUBLE NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

XML Format Required :

```
<DETAILS>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <CUSTOMERNAME>RAM</CUSTOMERNAME>
        <BILL>
            <BILLNO>1000</BILLNO>
            <BILLAMOUNT>3000</BILLAMOUNT>
        </BILL>
    </CUSTOMER>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <CUSTOMERNAME>RAJ</CUSTOMERNAME>
        <BILL>
            <BILLNO>1001</BILLNO>
            <BILLAMOUNT>3500</BILLAMOUNT>
        </BILL>
        <BILL>
            <BILLNO>1002</BILLNO>
            <BILLAMOUNT>5000</BILLAMOUNT>
        </BILL>
    </CUSTOMER>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <CUSTOMERNAME>RAVI</CUSTOMERNAME>
        <BILL>
            <BILLNO>1003</BILLNO>
            <BILLAMOUNT>3250</BILLAMOUNT>
        </BILL>
    </CUSTOMER>
</DETAILS>
```

Code i used so for :

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','xml');
    $cust=mysqli_query($con,"select * from customer");
    
    $xml= new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openURI("php://output");
    $xml->startDocument();
    $xml->setIndent(true);
    $xml->startElement('DETAILS');
    
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cust))
        {
            $xml->startElement('CUSTOMER');
            
                $xml->startElement('ID');
                $xml->writeRaw($row['ID']);
                $xml->endElement();

                $xml->startElement('CUSTOMERNAME');
                $xml->writeRaw($row['CUSTOMERNAME']);
                $xml->endElement();
                
                $xml->startElement('BILL');
                
                    $xml->startElement('BILLNO');
                    $xml->writeRaw($row['BILLNO']);
                    $xml->endElement();
                    
                    $xml->startElement('BILLAMOUNT');
                    $xml->writeRaw($row['BILLAMOUNT']);
                    $xml->endElement();
                    
                $xml->endElement();
            $xml->endElement();
        }
    $xml->endElement();
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    $xml->flush();
?>
```

Result i get :

```
<DETAILS>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <CUSTOMERNAME>RAM</CUSTOMERNAME>
        <BILL>
            <BILLNO>1000</BILLNO>
            <BILLAMOUNT>3000</BILLAMOUNT>
        </BILL>
    </CUSTOMER>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <CUSTOMERNAME>RAJ</CUSTOMERNAME>
        <BILL>
            <BILLNO>1001</BILLNO>
            <BILLAMOUNT>3500</BILLAMOUNT>
        </BILL>
    </CUSTOMER>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <CUSTOMERNAME>RAJ</CUSTOMERNAME>
        <BILL>
            <BILLNO>1002</BILLNO>
            <BILLAMOUNT>5000</BILLAMOUNT>
        </BILL>
    </CUSTOMER>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <CUSTOMERNAME>RAVI</CUSTOMERNAME>
            <BILL>
            <BILLNO>1003</BILLNO>
            <BILLAMOUNT>3250</BILLAMOUNT>
            </BILL>
    </CUSTOMER>
</DETAILS>
```

I am able to create the XML file but cannot group and loop through the MySQL data using customer ID in PHP to generate the XML file structure as required.

Comment: `$xml->startElement('CUSTOMER');` - makes no sense that you do that for _every_ row you are processing, if you do _not_ want all rows to create an individual CUSTOMER element. You need to start by implementing what's called a _control break_ logic, comparing the current row's ID with that of the previous one, to determine whether you need to create a new CUSTOMER element, or append a new BILL to the already existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to track which customer ID you are currently outputting and only put out a new customer element when this changes.

The minor difference is that after the first time round, you would also need to close the previous customers element (as shown in the code)...

```
$previuosCustomerID = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cust)) {
    // On change of customer, write out new element
    if ($row['ID'] != $previuosCustomerID) {
        // End previous Customer - but not the first time.
        if ($previuosCustomerID !== 0) {
            $xml->endElement();
        }
        $xml->startElement('CUSTOMER');

        $xml->startElement('ID');
        $xml->writeRaw($row['ID']);
        $xml->endElement();

        $xml->startElement('CUSTOMERNAME');
        $xml->writeRaw($row['CUSTOMERNAME']);
        $xml->endElement();

        $previuosCustomerID = $row['ID'];
    }

    // Write out individual Bill
    $xml->startElement('BILL');

    $xml->startElement('BILLNO');
    $xml->writeRaw($row['BILLNO']);
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement('BILLAMOUNT');
    $xml->writeRaw($row['BILLAMOUNT']);
    $xml->endElement();

    // Close Bill element
    $xml->endElement();
}
// Close last customer element
$xml->endElement();
// Close Details element
$xml->endElement();
```

Comment: Thanks your code works fine and now i can able to get the result as i expected.